# Do I have to apply VB6 SP6 to all DLL projects, of a Windows project?

Tags: vb6

I've decided to try and give service pack 6 for VB6, a try with our legacy app.  I'm hoping it will make the old app work better, with fewer crashes, so that we can continue work on migrating this app to .NET.  Anyway, this VB6 app has about a dozen DLL's we wrote, all in VB6, and all compiled with SP5.  Do I have to apply VB6 SP6 to all of the DLL projects, as well as the main VB6 Windows application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having done a chunk of work through both SP5 and SP6, I don't remember ever having to make code changes to support the service pack.

And yes, you'll have to rebuild all your sources (so all DLLs and executables).

Answer (score 3):

It would be wise to do so as you'll pick up any enhancements in the compiler etc.

Its going back a bit, but I don't think you'll find any major code changes to deal with.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking, too.